# what is the the natural expression of this Lambda expression and method reference in the method usage or it just don't have it?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[4];
        students[0] = new Student("guy1", 103, 334); // height / age （randomly written）
        students[1] = new Student("guy2", 87, 534);
        students[2] = new Student("guy3", 103, 232);
        students[3] = new Student("guy4", 110, 121);

        Arrays.sort(students, Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge)); // method reference
        Arrays.sort(students, Comparator.comparingInt(student -> student.getAge())); // Lambda expression
```

```
// the source code of the comparingInt method
>! public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
>! Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
>! return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
>!             (c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c1), keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c2));
>!     }
```

I konw that I need to send the object and the method to this method, But I am confused why I can't just send the Object and method as normal parameters like Comparator.comparingInt(Student, student.get age())) (I konw it doesn't work but if I don't use Lambda expression or method reference I need to create a class in this or what?)

what I do like this is failed:

```
      Arrays.sort(students, Comparator.comparingInt(students,c1,getAge) kinds of , actually all can't pass IDEA.

//        Animal a = new Animal() { former version
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                System.out.println("dog runs");
//            }
//        };

//        Animal a = () -> {
//            System.out.println("dog runs");
//        };
//
//        a.run();
```

like this, I konw the the former version of the simpify version,but I can't understand how the usage and change of comparingInt sorts of. My understanding about this is that I thought they also have the Lambda in their method body,so what outside need to do is just transfer the parameter about the object and method. But why in this way? I am curious whether there is some theory or just some rules I need to remember?

My description may be not very clearly,Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything like what you're trying to do.  The closest thing is to *not* use `comparingInt` and just write `(c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(c1.getAge(), c2.getAge())`.

`comparingInt` *just* takes a function to run on its arguments.  It does not, and cannot, take the arguments itself -- not directly, at least; you could of course write

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = comparingInt(Student::getAge);
comparator.compare(s1, s2);
```

Comment: The compareint method actually have done the lambda thing so I can't use lambda expression to create method so on and what I should do is sending the parameter in the method reference or lambda way what inside lambda expression needed instead of sending parameter directly like what I am trying to do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer is that you can't do this.

Comment: So I just use method refeence or Lambda like (student -> student.getAge()) to fill or stand?  the parameter into the source code[ (c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c1), keyExtractor.applyAsInt(c2)) ] because actually the compareint method have done the thing inside.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.